# Non-Lazy Static Initialization Block in C#

Tags: c#, static, initialization

I need to run some code to register a type for a factory pattern. I would do this in Java with a static initialization block or in C++ with a static constructor.

How do you do this in C#? That static constructor gets run lazily and since the type will never be referred to in the code, never gets registered.

EDIT: I tried a test to see the registration code work. This doesn't seem to be working though.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

[assembly: AssemblyTest.RegisterToFactory("hello, world!")]

namespace AssemblyTest
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    sealed class RegisterToFactoryAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public RegisterToFactoryAttribute(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Registered {0}", name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about in a constructor for an `assembly level attribute`?

### Example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class RegisterToFactoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type TypeToRegister { get; set; }

    public RegisterToFactoryAttribute(Type typeToRegister)
    {
        TypeToRegister = typeToRegister;

        // Registration code
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[assembly:RegisterToFactory(typeof(MyClass))]
```

#### --EDIT on Assembly Level Attributes--

After doing some research, I figured it will only load the assembly attributes if they are queried:

### Example:

```
object[] attributes =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(RegisterToFactoryAttribute), false);
```

or

```
object[] attributes =
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

Don't know why but putting this code @ the program load should do it.

--EDIT--

I almost forgot:

Have you considered using [`MEF`](http://mef.codeplex.com/)?? It's a great solution to this problem.

### Example:

```
class MyFactory
{
    [ImportMany("MyFactoryExport")]
    public List<Object> Registrations { get; set; }

    public MyFactory()
    {
        AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}

[Export("MyFactoryExport")]
class MyClass1
{ }

[Export("MyFactoryExport")]
class MyClass2
{ }

[Export("MyFactoryExport")]
class MyClass3
{ }
```

Comment: "'assembly' is not a valid attribute location for this declaration. Valid attribute locations for this declaration are 'type'. All attributes in this block will be ignored." What does this mean?

Comment: Put `[assembly:RegisterToFactory(typeof(MyClass))]` in Assembly.cs in your project or at the top of any file.

Comment: @Jonathan you put the [assembly:derpaherpattribute()] *inside of a namespace declaration* `namespace herp{[assembly:thisfails()]}` remove the attribute definition from the namespace scope.

Comment: Okay, fixed that. When does this code get run? I changed it to accept a string and had the register function print something, but there's no printing when I run the assembly. Putting the code in the first post.

Comment: Put a `breakpoint` in that code. It should execute whenever the assembly is loaded.

Comment: @decyclone I tried adding a print statement and putting a breakpoint on it in the main function. The "Registered" line didn't get printed. Is it a problem that it's not getting compiled to an assembly, but directly into the executable?

Comment: Yep, that works. I can query the assembly inside of the Factory and register the types to the factory then.